# iPhone: Wrong alert noise

Tags: iphone, audio

I've got my iPhone set to use the Telegraph alert noise:

[image: iphone sounds]

But whenever I get an alert from Twitter, I always hear three noises: Tri-tone, then Telegraph, then Tri-tone.

The triplicate of alerts is slightly bothering, but not overly. I think they're due to both the Mail and the GMail apps announcing I have mail.  I'm not sure which is which, but I hear Tri-tone and Telegraph when I get mail.

I'm just sick of Tri-tone, and would rather not use it at all.

Is there any way I can change the Twitter alert and the GMail(or Mail) alert to use Telegraph rather than Tri-tone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in Mail app should use the Telegraph tone that you've set for New Mail.

The Twitter client and the GMail app have their own alert tones, and if those apps don't let you change the sound I'm afraid the OS can't either.